# Numpy matrix from text file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a matrix into a text file and need to read the file in another python script. The second script needs to get the text back into a numpy array. I have been struggling to find out how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Two examples of the array are given below:

```
[[ 0.  0. -0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

or

```
[[ 0.          0.         -0.03011621]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.06023241]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.01204648]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save to a text file, use [np.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

```
In [115]: x = np.zeros((10, 3))

In [116]: np.savetxt('/tmp/test.out', x)
```

To load, use np.loadtxt or [np.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
In [117]: y = np.genfromtxt('/tmp/test.out')

In [120]: y.shape
Out[120]: (10, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks ubutbu! About this method - If I use one script to write to the text file and another to read, does the OS prevent conflict between the programs - ie does it prevent the reading and writing from occurring simultaneously? If so what is the protocol used?

Comment: There is no built-in protection against reading the file prematurely. One thing you could do is use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to spawn the reading process after the writer is done.