# Read in a bunch of txt files and create an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, import

So I have this code in MATLAB

```
txtFiles = dir('*.txt') ; %loads txt files
N = length(txtFiles) ; 

for i = 1:N
    data = importdata(txtFiles(i).name);
    x = data(:,1);
    udata(:,i) = data(:,2) ;
end
```

It basically creates an array where each column is a different data set. How might one replicate this in Python with say Numpy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy matrix from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187081/numpy-matrix-from-text-file)

Comment: Is the resulting data most like a two-dimensional array (matrix), or more like tabular data, since each column is a different data set?

Comment: So it ends up with each column being a single set of data so for my case I have 50 columns and 100 rows

Comment: No, I'm asking if the result is in principle tabular data, or a 2D array. This changes how you approach reading and analysing the data (i.e., with what tools).